# KMM zoom value is always returned as 1f in detectTransformGestures method on iOS devices

Tags: android, ios, kotlin-multiplatform, compose-multiplatform

I have worked on Compose Multiplatform. We used PointerEvent.calculateZoom() to get the zoom value from the detectTransformGestures method and were using that value to scale the Canvas drawing.

It works perfectly on the Android, but the same code does not work on iOS. On digging more on why the feature was not working on iOS, we found that the method used to get the Zoom scale value, PointerEvent.calculateZoom() always returns 1f in iOS device even when the user does two finger zoom gesture on the screen.

The event.changes list returns 1 for iOS but 2 for Android is the main reason for this discrepancy.

```
forEachGesture {
            awaitPointerEventScope {
                awaitFirstDown(requireUnconsumed = false)
            }
            awaitPointerEventScope {
                var zoom = 1f
                var pastTouchSlop = false
                val touchSlop = viewConfiguration.touchSlop

                do {
                    val event = awaitPointerEvent()
                    val canceled = event.changes.any { it.isConsumed }
                    if (event.changes.size == 1) break
                    else if (event.changes.size == 2) {
                        if (isZoomAllowed) {
                            if (!canceled) {
                                val zoomChange = event.calculateZoom()
                                if (!pastTouchSlop) {
                                    zoom *= zoomChange
                                    val centroidSize =
                                        event.calculateCentroidSize(useCurrent = false)
                                    val zoomMotion = abs(1 - zoom) * centroidSize
                                    if (zoomMotion > touchSlop) pastTouchSlop = true
                                }
                                if (pastTouchSlop) {
                                    if (zoomChange != 1f) onZoom(zoomChange)
                                    event.changes.forEach { if (it.positionChanged()) it.consume() }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    } else break
                } while (!canceled && event.changes.any { it.pressed })
            }
        }
```

Why is the above discrepancy happening? How can I fix this?

I tried using just the Centroid value to calculate the zoom value, but that was restricting the user to scroll the Canvas horizontally.

Comment: looks like a bug of compose for iOS, not sure what answer are you trying to get here - better report it to the maintainers

Comment: Yea, please register this issue on https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue